# Query IN that matches all

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables

```
Report
----------
report_id
name

Template
------------
template_id
report_id
```

A report can have many templates. How can I query to get the Report that has Templates matching a list of items

For example if template had these rows

```
Template_ID  | Report_ID
---------------------------
a              1
b              1
c              2
d              3
```

When selecting reports I need to make sure ALL the templates in my table are in the filer criteria, it does not matter if there are addtional items in the filter criteria not in the database.

**Examples**

find all reports for Template  `a,b,c`. 
This would return report  1  because `a,b` is a subset of `a,b,c` , also report 2 as it is a `c` is a subset of  `a,b,c`

find all reports for Template `a`  - This would no rows. Because there are no reports that just have a ONLY as `a` template

find all reports for Template `c`  - This would only return report 2.

find all reports for Template `c,d`  - This would only return report 2 and 3 as `c` is a subset of `c,d` and `d` is also a subset of `c,d`.

find all reports for Template `d,e`  - This would only return report 3 as `d` is a subset of `c,e`

Comment: `c` is also a subset of `a,b,c`, why wouldn't your first example return report 2 as well?

Comment: Surely reports for "a,b,c" should reports 1 and 2? As well as a only has report 1, surely that would return report 1?

Comment: @lanzz  yes sorry you are correct, I will update that my mistake. BugFinder living up to your name I see =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f9d6/5)

```
select distinct Report_id 
   from Template T
   where Template_id in ('d','e')
   and NOT EXISTS 
      (select T1.Report_id 
        from Template T1
        where Template_id not in ('d','e')
        and T.Report_id=T1.Report_id)
```

Comment: awesome  never knew  SQLFiddle  existed, and your code works WELL

Answer (score 1):

Find all of the reports with a template in your set; subtract from that all of the reports with a template NOT in your set.

Answer (score 1):

This query returns `2`, which I think is correct from the description:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.report_id
  FROM template t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
      FROM template
      WHERE template_id NOT IN ('b', 'c')
  ) t2 ON t1.report_id = t2.report_id
  WHERE t1.template_id IN ('b', 'c')
    AND t2.template_id IS NULL
```

**Edit**: This is basically Scott's answer, but I hadn't seen it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach. I like this because you don't need to duplicate the list of templates:

```
SELECT t1.report_id
  FROM (
    SELECT report_id, COUNT(*) AS report_count
      FROM template
      GROUP BY report_id
  ) t1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT report_id, COUNT(*) AS report_count
      FROM template
      WHERE template_id IN ('b', 'c')
      GROUP BY report_id
  ) t2 ON t1.report_id = t2.report_id
  WHERE t1.report_count = t2.report_count
```

Comment: thanks for both your excellent answers they seem to work perfectly I could just copy and paste them into SQLFiddle by valex and they just work! Wish I could choose more then one correct answer. Going with Valex as looking at the execution plan it seems like his would perform quicker?

Comment: Profiling would be best but failing that then it would be reasonable to consider the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct report_id from template where template_id in (<list>)
minus
select distinct report_id from template where template_id not in (<list>)
```

Comment: Thanks but could not get this to work as minus seems to be Oracle or DB specific command and not standard